# Using Linq to determine the missing combination of records

Tags: linq

Let me start to explain with an example.

```
var vProducts = new[] {
    new { Product = "A", Location ="Y", Month = "January", Demand = 50 },
    new { Product = "A", Location ="Y", Month = "February", Demand = 100 },
    new { Product = "A", Location ="Y", Month = "March", Demand = 20 },
    new { Product = "A", Location ="Y", Month = "June", Demand = 10 }
};

var vPeriods = new[] {
    new { Priority = 1, Month = "January" },
    new { Priority  = 2, Month = "February" },
    new { Priority  = 3, Month = "March" },
    new { Priority  = 4, Month = "April" },
    new { Priority  = 5, Month = "May" },
    new { Priority  = 6, Month = "June" }
};

var vAll = from p in vProducts
       from t in vPeriods
       select new
           {
             Product = p.Product,
             Location = p.Location,
             Period = t.Priority,
             PeriodName = t.Month,
             Demand = p.Demand
           };
```

This above query will create all combinations of Products & Period. But, I need to get a list of all products along with the ones that do not have matching Month as shown below.

example

```
Product      Location      Priority        Month    Demand
  A              Y            1           January     50
  A              Y            2          February    100
  A              Y            3           March       20
  A              Y            4           April       null
  A              Y            5           May         null
  A              Y            6           June        10
```

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Can you make your title a little better? The current one doesn't really describe your question.

Comment: Tried to update the title as best I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do a [left outer join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx), it will go something like:

```
var res = from period in vPeriods
                  join product in vProducts on period.Month equals product.Month into bla
                  from p in bla.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new { period.Month, period.Priority, Product = p == null ? null : p.Product, Demand = p == null ? -1 : p.Demand };

  foreach (var a in res)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", a.Product, a.Month, a.Demand));
            }
```

Of course that products that do not have matching months don't have locations etc. (as you stated in your example)

Comment: @Vitality. Left join is not going to work for my case, since I need to create the records who don't have a matching Period, with null as default values.

Comment: @user320587, this is an OUTER join. It will give you exactly what you need. The default -1 values could be converted to nulls afterwards, the important thing is that you get an indication that they are missing. 

I strongly suggest you execute the query to see the results for yourself and read the documentation I referenced.

Comment: @Vitality. Yup, I tried your query with LinqPad and I am able to determine the missing periods, after which I can perform a select many with the original table and just get the missing records. Thanks

Comment: @user320587 Great. Make sure you read the documentation too. Linq is one of the greatest things that happened to the .Net industry in the last decade. It is absolutely essential to know it through and through :-)